# How to Disable the Ctrl-K google chrome shortcut on my Chromebook because it keeps interfering with my google slides linking option

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Generally, I seriously don't really know what happened, but yesterday, when I was busy linking my google slides buttons for a google slides game project to a slide link, the `Ctrl`-`k` suddently bring up the Search functionality in the Chrome address bar instead of giving me the option to link one slide to another link. This never happened before, and I never got this command whenever I did `Ctrl`-`k` no matter what I did. So I'm quite confused on what happened and what to do. Also, this is on a School Chromebook [Model N18Q7 Acer] so please don't recommend me to install extentions...

Sorry if I sound unclear, my english isn't really good. I'll try to add some images to the text to try and explain what I meant [Typically what happen when I click `Ctrl`-`K` from the days before Yesterday in google slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTIHY.png) + [What happens now when I click `Ctrl`-`K` ever since yesterday in google slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RermB.png)

(TLDR; How do I disable the `Ctrl`-`k` from showing the search bar in google slides because it never happened to me the days before yesterday and it's interferring with my linking option.)